# Download multiple files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm very new to this so am learning by trial and error.

I have a javascript which so far is authorising access to a users Google Drive. It creates an array of some files it finds and I can access the meta data to get the DownloadURL of each file.

```
function downloadFile() {
            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);
        }


        function makeRequest() {
            var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
                    'method': 'GET',
                    'params': {'q': 'title contains "This"'} // retrieve all files with a filename that begins with the word "This"
                });

            request.execute(function(resp) {

                for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                    var dlUrl = resp.items[i].downloadUrl; //this is the url extracted from the request
                    var finalDlUrl = dlUrl.split("&gd=true");//the url needs to be trimmed so the last 8 characters are ignored in order to work
                   window.location.assign(finalDlUrl);


                }
            });
```

How do I get the script to loop through each of the file array elements and download each one. I know to use a 'for loop' but what is the actual way of triggering the file downloads so they appear in my browser downloads folder.

also, and it may be related, what is the syntax to include the alt=media parameter in a http request when using `gapi.client.request({/* etc */})`

Comment: Please post a code sample so that we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an iframe and set the src to the DownloadURL value. You may need to set a timeout...

```
    function downloadFile() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);
    }


    function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/drive/v2/files',
                'method': 'GET',
                'params': {'q': 'title contains "This"'} // retrieve all files with a filename that begins with the word "This"
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
            for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                var dlUrl = resp.items[i].downloadUrl; //this is the url extracted from the request
                var finalDlUrl = dlUrl.split("&gd=true");//the url needs to be trimmed so the last 8 characters are ignored in order to work
               downloadUrl(finalDlUrl);
            }
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url) {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = url;
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
```

Here is some code that might download the files in sequence:

```
    function downloadFile() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);
    }

    function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.request({
                'path': '/drive/v2/files',
                'method': 'GET',
                'params': {'q': 'title contains "This"'}
            });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
            downloadFiles(0, resp.items);
        });
    }

    function downloadFiles(current, list)
    {
        var next = current + 1;
        if(next == list.length) {
            return;
        }

        var dlUrl = resp.items[next].downloadUrl;
        var finalDlUrl = dlUrl.split("&gd=true");

        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = finalDlUrl;
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.onload = function() {
            downloadFiles(next, list);
        };
    }
```

Comment: thanks.  I tried the window.location command and it worked when there is just 1 file but I could not get it to loop around each file in the array.  here's what I tried:

Comment: request.execute(function(resp) {
                   for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                   var dlUrl = resp.items[i].downloadUrl;
                   var finalDlUrl = dlUrl.split("&gd=true");
                   window.location.assign(finalDlUrl[i]);
                    }
                });

Comment: sorry again!! I pasted an old version it should read window.location.assign(finalDlUrl)   i.e there is no array index.  the code works but only downloads the first file and there are 3 matching files in my drive.

Comment: Hi  thanks for this.  I'm not sure how to fit this in.  I've posted my actual code in an answer below are you able to merge you code into my code so I can see where it fits together.  cheers

Comment: ah wonderful !!!!  that works a treat.  thank you so much.  I've ticked the button for correct answer but it wouldn't let me tick the up answer as I have no reputation. happy to click anything else that ups your kudos. thanks again

Comment: Hi again!  this code works great but I've just come across a limitation.  the code is now live on our server but we are now working with up to 300 files at a time to download.  chrome falls apart downloading this many files at once.  Is there a way to wait for 1 download to finish before it starts the next.  Maybe this is what you meant when you said "You may need to set a timeout..."  thanks

Comment: @MartinPearson I added a code sample that might accomplish what you need.